# You have an error in your SQL syntax. MySQL Selectgiving error with LIKE and

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a MySQL select for use in a mysql_query function, but I keep getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN Orgs ON Jobs.CustOrgID = Orgs.ID 
            LEFT JOIN Persons ON Jobs.CustPer' at line 11
```

I've tried everything and searched everywhere, but nothing seems to be working. All help is appreciated.

```
 $Qry = "SELECT 

     Jobs.ID, 
     'Jobs.Status',
     Jobs.JobNum, 
     'Orgs.Nme', 
     'Persons.FirstNme',
     'Persons.LastNme',
     'JobTypes.JobType',
     'Jobs.Dsc',
     'Jobs.Notes'
     FROM Jobs ";

     if($column !== null && $text !== null) {
        $Qry .= "WHERE " . $column . " LIKE '%" . $text . "%' ";
     }

     $Qry .= "LEFT JOIN Orgs ON Jobs.CustOrgID = Orgs.ID 
         LEFT JOIN Persons ON Jobs.CustPersonID = Persons.ID
         LEFT JOIN JobTypes ON Jobs.JobTypeID = JobTypes.ID 
         ORDER BY JobNum";
```

SOLUTION:

```
     SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     LEFT JOIN ...
     LEFT JOIN ...
     WHERE ...
     ORDER BY ...
```

My WHERE was in the wrong place, it should come after the two LEFT JOINS.

Comment: The WHERE should be after the JOINs and before the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inserting the WHERE in the wrong place. It must come AFTER the joins:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN ...
LEFT JOIN ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: of course, like @echo_me said below, the quoting's incorrect as well. OP will fix the where stuff and still end up with more errors.

Answer (score 3):

you should use backticks instead of single quotes , or you dont have to use backticks if they are not reserved keywords or separated strings .

try this :

```
     $Qry = "SELECT 

 `Jobs`.`ID`, 
 `Jobs`.`Status`,
 `Jobs`.`JobNum`, 
 `Orgs`.`Nme`, 
 `Persons`.`FirstNme`,
 `Persons`.`LastNme`,
 `JobTypes`.`JobType`,
 `Jobs`.`Dsc`,
 `Jobs`.`Notes`
 FROM Jobs ";
```

Comment: You've answered the unasked next question :] (+1 anyway as it's almost as important as the first error)

Comment: @AD7six i know i have mentioned it . its just because he used single quotes so i said instead you should use backticks.

Comment: Thank you for this guys. Is there any reason for this because I didn't see it in my reading?

Comment: @Dubastot `SELECT "Jobs.id" FROM Jobs` will return the string "Jobs.id" - not the field value.